# Description attribute changes in AD via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I've created a Powershell script to help with user termination within my company.

The rest of it works but the part that's intended to change the description attribute occasionally fails to work. It appears to be limited to accounts which already have an entry in their description field but, again, doesn't always fail. I've added an extra step to remove any existing description first but to no avail.

Here's the relevant part of the script:

```
Set-ADUser -Identity $Username -Clear description
Set-ADUser -Identity $Username -Description "Terminated $termDateinit" -AccountExpirationdate $time
Get-ADUser -Identity $Username | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU"
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What you have should work fine, and you should not need that first line. What error are you getting when it fails?

Comment: The first line was added as an attempt to fix the problem. I figured something about the description field already being filled in may have been the problem so, logically, clearing it out would fix it. I don't get an error per se, it just doesn't work. For example, the AD account for Joe Blogs should have the description Terminated 18/02/2015. Instead, it will remain as, say, Field Technician. As mentioned above, everything else works. The Expiry date sets correctly, the account gets moved to the correct OU. All of that.

Comment: Add try - catch to your code. You need to check error in catch block (there are a few examples of this).